# JavaScript is not working with JSP page in ECLIPSE IDE

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZiF.png)

This is form for Student Registration which collect and send information to the Servlet "StudentRegisterSrv" which is mentioned at "action". but the JS code, which is there for password confirmation matching is not working. I have tried both internal(on same file) and external JS(by link).

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register | Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPassword(form) { 
                password1 = form.password.value; 
                password2 = form.password2.value; 
                // If password not entered 
                if (password == '') 
                    alert ("Please enter Password"); 
                // If confirm password not entered 
                else if (password2 == '') 
                    alert ("Please enter confirm password");                       
                // If Not same return False.     
                else if (password != password2) { 
                    alert ("\nPassword did not match: Please try again...") 
                    return false; 
                }  
                // If same return True. 
                else{ 
                    alert("Password Match: Welcome to GeeksforGeeks!") 
                    return true; 
                } 
            } 
</script>            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/body.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Student Registration</h1>
    <form action="StudentRegisterSrv" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>  <br><br> 
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>  <br> <br> 
        <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile No." required>    <br><br> 
        <input id="pwd1" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>   <br><br>    
        <input id="pwd2" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Password Again" required>    <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" onSubmit = "return checkPassword(this)"> 
        <input type="reset" value=" RESET">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `onSubmit="return checkPassword()"` to your form tag so that on click of submit button this gets called and if `false` will return from js then form will not get submit else if `true` form will get submit.Also i have use `document.getElementById("pwd1").value` to get values of password fields and fixed typos as well.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function checkPassword() {
  //get value by id
  var password1 = document.getElementById("pwd1").value;
  var password2 = document.getElementById("pwd2").value;
  // If password not entered 
  if (password1 == '')
    alert("Please enter Password");
  // If confirm password not entered 
  else if (password2 == '')
    alert("Please enter confirm password");
  // If Not same return False.     
  else if (password1 != password2) {
    alert("\nPassword did not match: Please try again...")
    return false; //will return false and prevent form to submit
  }
  // If same return True. 
  else {
    alert("Password Match: Welcome to GeeksforGeeks!")
    return true; //will return true and submit the form
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Student Registration</h1>
<form name="form" action="StudentRegisterSrv" method="post" onSubmit="return checkPassword()">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required> <br><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> <br> <br>
  <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile No." required> <br><br>
  <input id="pwd1" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required> <br><br>
  <input id="pwd2" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Password Again" required> <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
  <input type="reset" value=" RESET">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried what u said, but it's still not working.

Comment: In Eclipse IDE, while writing JavaScript, code completion(ctrl + space) is also not working. Is this related to above problem.

Comment: Have u tried it running ? Is it working over there with you ?

Comment: yes , you can run above code snippet and check onces .Also check if your browser console showing any error ? I tried this in netbeans .

Comment: Okay, let me try and check console.

Comment: I tried it in online code running engine, but it is not giving that ERROR msg when 'password1' is not matching 'password2' . And NO Error in CONSOLE

Comment: When i changed the JSP to HTML, it is running and showing ERROR msg, but not in JSP.

Comment: Can you just put `alert("in");` inside your script and remove all other codes and then run that jsp page again to see if that simple alert shows or not ? Also check [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaScript/article.html) page.

Comment: Yes, <alert("in")> is working FINE, if I commented out everything else. So, can u see the problem now.

Comment: That simply means your scripts runs in jsp page. Did you make changes in code as per I did in above code snippet provided ? because this should run as well.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am just confused.
This JS code function is right, working in another editor. Eclipse is supporting JS (`alert("in");` worked). Then how these two don't work together.